# best way to get unreplicated attributes values LDAP Search

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, ldap

Is there any best way to get a most accurate value from unreplicated attributes from LDAP provider?.

As far as I know that if the attribute is not replicated we should check it through all DCs. Given an example here `modifyTimeStamp` attribute which is not replicated, what is the best way to track its value given on 10 different DCs?

Does it work in the same way with other attributes? In this case with `badpwdcount` attribute?.

IMO, with `badpwdcount` we don't need to check through all DCs, because it will centralize (be updated ) in PDC afterwards.

Comment: For how many objects/accounts do you need to track it? What is the end purpose here?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen approximately 50 000 objects. Just for investigation purpose

Comment: In that case I would either 1) parallelly query the 10 DC's for all 50.000 users, or 2) build a custom application (probably easier in C# than is PowerShell) to [poll the directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677627(v=vs.85).aspx) periodically. Option 1 is easy to implement but option 2 less resource intensive

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen so I should take 10 values from 10 DC's, or just take the nearest one with current time ?. Do you think all unreplicated attributes are later on updated in PDC as `badpasswdcount` attr. ?

Comment: Again, it depends on what you're trying to achieve ("investigation purposes" is pretty vague, *what* are you investigating). If you're trying to track a timestamp stored in a *non-replicated* attribute then yes, you need to take all 10 values, sort them and take the latest one to get the latest modification time. Forget about `badpwdcount` btw, it's special and governed by immediate replication, don't rely on its behavior to understand regular non-replicated attributes